# Cookies save and work fine in Insomnia app, but they do not work in my react application

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a login page and a register page. When I register a user from the frontend form, it creates a new user. But when I try to log in to the user, I get the 200 status and my data back, but I guess it doesn't set the cookie. When I try to go to a protected route that only a logged-in user can access, I get the error I made from the backend which is "You are unauthenticated". How do I send or set the cookie in the front end too?  Everything really works fine in the Insomnia app, the cookies get set.

this is how I'm making the post-login request

```
  const submit = async (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
const data = { username, password };
try {
  await axios.post(path, data).then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  });
    } catch (err) {
  setLoading(false);
  setError(err.message);
}
```

Comment: First thing first we have to make sure about cookies are set correctly or not. By the way, can you check cookies from Developer Tool -> Application -> Cookies path?

Comment: @OnurkanBakırcı They don't appear in there either. What do you think could be wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to set cookie from server or client? If you try to set cookie from server, can you share login endpoint method code?

Comment: Please check, I just answered my question with the server-side login code. @OnurkanBakırcı

Answer (score 0):

this is the login controller in the server side.

```
const login = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const oneUser = await Users.findOne({ username: req.body.username });
    if (!oneUser) {
      return res.status(403).json("No such user in the database");
    }
    const isPassword = bcryptjs.compare(req.body.password, oneUser.password);

    if (!isPassword) {
      return res.status(500).json(`${req.body.username} Password is incorrect`);
    }

    const token = jwt.sign(
      {
        id: oneUser._id,
        isAdmin: oneUser.isAdmin,
      },
      process.env.jwt
    );

    const { password, ...others } = oneUser._doc;
    res
      .cookie("access_token", token, {
        httpOnly: true,
      })
      .status(200)
      .json({ ...others });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you check your cookies from development tool whether are set or not after removing ```httpOnly``` flag? Because if you are in development environment, this can cause problem.

Comment: Dug my way through the net and I finally did something that worked. I was sending an Axios post request and I found out that by default, it doesn't send credentials so i had to send the request like 

axios.post(url, data, {withCredentisals: true} );

On the server-side, i had to do this too so I don't run into any cors problem 

app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: "http://localhost:3000" }));

localhost 3000 is the react application host. @OnurkanBakırcı

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).